# Iterating conditionally over a combinations of objects

Tags: python

I'm working on a little nutrition program and want to find the best combinations of certain foods that will meet a few requirements in terms of calories and macronutrients. For the purposes of this question, I will only focus on target calories.

I have data from an API that will tell me things about a given food. For example:

```
egg = Food(FOOD_IDS["Boiled Egg"])
print(egg.macros.__dict__)
```

Result:

```
{'protein_grams': 6.0, 'fat_grams': 4.5, 'carb_grams': 1.0, 'calories': 68.5}
```

What I'm trying to do is find the possible combinations of my available foods that will add up to a target number of calories.

So if I have `egg`, `rice`, `chicken` in a collection of `foods`, how can I find all the possible combinations of these foods that sum to e.g. 3000 calories?

I was thinking of using `random` to continually gather foods in a `while` loop until the calories target was met, but I am worried about performance as my food list grows. I've used `product`, `combinations`, and `permutations` from the `itertools` library before, but I don't see how those methods could be applied here since I am intending to iterate within a boundary condition.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
def get_daily_food_options(self):
    target = 3000
    food_combinations = []
    groceries = []
    groceries.append(Food(FOOD_IDS["Boiled Egg"]))
    groceries.append(Food(FOOD_IDS["Brown Rice"]))
    groceries.append(Food(FOOD_IDS["Chicken Breast"]))
    num_iterations = 100 # I have to manually change this to get more/less results
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        temp_combination = []
        current_calories = 0
        while current_calories < target:
            food = choice(groceries) # random (not smart)
            temp_combination.append(food)
            current_calories += food.macros.calories
        food_combinations.append(temp_combination)
    return food_combinations
```

This works... but is there a smarter way to do this?

For simplicity, you could use these int calorie values for testing: 
egg = 68.5
rice = 169.5
chicken = 114.5

Here's some sample output from my program to show how I'm digesting the results:

```
Mixed Nuts (28.0g per serving) : 3 servings
Good Seed bread (28.0g per serving) : 2 servings
Brown Rice (45.0g per serving) : 1 servings
Pineapple (77.0g per serving) : 5 servings
Sweet Potato (120.0g per serving) : 4 servings
Boiled Egg (45.0g per serving) : 2 servings
Green Peas (89.0g per serving) : 5 servings
Salmon (113.0g per serving) : 7 servings
Chicken Breast (112.0g per serving) : 3 servings
Spinach (85.0g per serving) : 1 servings
```

Comment: What about this? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-all-combinations-that-adds-upto-given-number-2/

Comment: `current_calories += sum([f.macros.calories for f in temp_combination])` is probably not neccessary since the `current_calories` has the number of calories before the current while iteration. Since each while iteration adds a food into `temp_combination`, you just need to add up the `current_calories` with the calories of the food you selected, which is simply `current_calories += food.macros.calories`. With this, you can avoid an extra O(n) computation in the `sum([f.macros.calories for f in temp_combination])` expression.

Comment: @VietHTran good catch, thanks

Comment: Have you looked into linear programming? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html scipy is a great package. It doesn't answer your question directly but you should be able to find a list of optimal solutions. Also useful: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6021504/

Comment: @DavisHerring - each food has a notion of "serving size" so one instance of an egg, is one serving based on what the API defines as a serving size in grams. calories-per-serving is how the calories are defined per quantity. I've added some some sample output with many foods that total roughly 3000 calories.

Comment: @JacobIRR: Is “roughly 3000” the goal, or need it be exact?

Comment: @DavisHerring it needs to be at least 3000 but can be over 3000 by an epsilon of say 100 calories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program takes a total calorie count and a list of integers representing the calorie content of individual food items. It attempts to find the multiple of those food items that will add up *exactly* to the required total calorie count:

```
from itertools import product

def get_combinations(total_calories, calorie_counts):
    n = len(calorie_counts)
    max_factors = [total_calories // calorie_counts[i] for i in range(n)]
    for t in product(*(range(factors + 1) for factors in max_factors)):
        calorie_count = sum([t[i] * calorie_counts[i] for i in range(n)])
        if calorie_count == total_calories:
            print(t)


get_combinations(3000, [300, 150, 200])
```

If you insist on at least one serving of each food item then change the for loop to:

```
for t in product(*(range(1, factors + 1) for factors in max_factors)):
```

The idea is that if the total calories is X and a food item is Y calories, the only possible number of servings of that food item is in the range [0..X//Y] (or [1..X//Y] if you insist there be at least one serving). So if there are N food items the program does an exhaustive trial of all possible combinations of food items by generating tuples of length N where each tuple is one possible combination to try.

[See demo](http://ideone.com/HrMKrW)

Comment: I really like that this has a sorted output. I'm going to plug this into my larger context and see how it works

Comment: I think I get what the `max_factors` is doing, but when I run this with 13 foods, it runs for a very long time (It's been five minutes now). Does this imply that I need to run this through some kind of data science package/lib that has its mathematical operations optimized at the C level? I don't see any way of optimizing it further.

Comment: @JacobIRR Well, with 13 foods you have what is essentially 13 nested loops that test every possible combination of food item servings where each serving can vary from 0 to its maximum allowed value (I now wish I had named variable `max_factors` to something like `max_servings`). It could run for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The usual odometer-like approach here is

```
def combos(menu,target,extra):  # menu: list of values
  # Put the biggest first for efficiency
  # and to avoid large shortfalls:
  order=sorted(enumerate(menu),key=lambda e: -e[1])
  # Construct inverse permutation:
  inv=[None]*len(menu)
  for i,(j,_) in enumerate(order): inv[j]=i
  for c in combos0([v for _,v in order],target,extra,[]):
    yield [c[i] for i in inv]
def combos0(menu,target,extra,pfx):
  v=menu[len(pfx)]
  # Leave no budget unspent:
  if len(pfx)==len(menu)-1:
    n=-(-target//v)  # ceiling division
    if target+extra>=n*v: yield pfx+[n]
  else:
    for i in range((target+extra)//v+1):
      for c in combos0(menu,target-i*v,extra,pfx+[i]): yield c
```

Your call here would be `combos([f.macros.calories for f in foods],3000,100)`.

Comment: `for i,(j,_) in order` throws `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` in Python 3.7. Was it supposed to be `enumerate(order)`?

Comment: @JacobIRR: Yes, of course; posting code from a mobile device has its limitations.  Edited.